# Automatic horizontal resizing

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way I could make a text box in PowerPoint only resize horizontally, rather than vertically when typing more text than its space allows?

It should work like this: A person typing in the text box would only see it resize horizontally when there isn't more space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When inserting a text box do not size the text box (don't make a box). Just click once to insert it. The text box will not have a specific size to move the text to the 2nd row, so the text you will insert will go horizontally all the way.
2. If you already have text boxes (maybe part of a template) you can right click the text box and go to `Format Shape`. From here go to `Text Box` and uncheck the "Wrap text in shape" box. This will have the same result.